# Sorting issue while getting product from category ID using REST Api

Tags: magento2, rest-api, category-products

I am reviewing Magento 2 REST API.
I am trying to get all the products from its category ID using below API:

> GET    /V1/categories/:categoryId/products

Some how I am unable to get product details (Can't even get its name and price) and it simply return product SKU, ID and Position in response. Moreover I cannot apply any kind of sorting or pagination like if i want to limit response array count to 10 or 20 then i cannot do it.

I tried to apply Search criteria as well but found no luck.

It works perfectly with Product Listing API

> GET    /V1/products

Please help me out. May be I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try posting something like this:

```
[POST] rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[page_size]=50&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=11
```

11 = the category id

Comment: That was perfect. Its kind of loop hole in Magento 2.X API